# How to make a xml file parameterized

Tags: xml

Is it possible to pass arguments in xml file, and store the value of them in another xml file?

```
<Installer>
     <Name>HelloWorld Installer</Name>
     <Version>1.0.0</Version>
     <Title>HelloWorld</Title>
     <Publisher>Qt-Project</Publisher>
     <!-- Directory name is used in component.xml -->
     <StartMenuDir>HelloWorld</StartMenuDir>
     <TargetDir>@HomeDir@/HelloWorld</TargetDir> 
</Installer>
```

Instead of HelloWorld I want to pass an argument.

Comment: Every tag is an argument.  You want to be able to modify xml as required changing values before sending file.

Answer (score 0):

XML is a data format. Arguments are something you pass to a function or a command line program. So … no, not as such.

You could use a programming language to write a program that has a function (or command line interface) which takes arguments and then generates XML based on it.

Comment: Thanks, so it cant be paramterized